# Accessing the contents of Detail section in BIRT report

Tags: birt

I am working with BIRT report, to generate it in xml formate I am writing emitter(BIRT plugin). I need an xml report which contains some repeated sections on the basis of some section in the same report. I am using subReports for that. So the report strcture is like

---

```
List--
  Header--
    Table---(No header and footer)
       details--- 
          Cell----
             Text(Multiple text here) Some static section and dynamic data
List Details ----
   Table--(No header and footer)(This table will be repeated for every record in the header part)
      Details--
          Cell --
             Multiple Text elements ()`
List Footer---- Empty
```

As I am writing the emitter, I need to extract the the content of all the text elements which are in the Cell elements mainly. Now Following is the code in My emitter for sartCell method.

```
    public void startCell(ICellContent arg0) {
    System.out.println("text in Cell:: ");
    System.out.println("text in Cell:: " + arg0.getInstanceID());

    for(Object ie : arg0.getChildren())
    {
        if(ie instanceof  LabelContent)
        {
            LabelContent lc = (LabelContent)ie;
            stringBuilder.append(lc.getText());
            System.out.println(lc.getText());
        }
        else if(ie instanceof ForeignContent)
        {
            ForeignContent fc = (ForeignContent)ie;
            stringBuilder.append(fc.getRawValue());
            System.out.println(fc.getRawValue());
        }

    }

}
```

I am able to access the Cell and all it's text content with this logic. But I want to do the same thing with all the cells of the Table in Details section of List. **The problem is that Cells in the details section are giving null on ICellContent.getChildren().**

And yes My startText method is not getting called at all. Following is the declaration of my emmiter,

public class XmlEmittor extends ContentEmitterAdapter {...}

Following is the rptDesign strcture,

```
<List>
    <Header>
           <Table><Detail><Cell><Text>...DynamicText....</Text>.....</Table>
    </Header>
    <Detail>
           <Table><Detail><Cell><Text>...DynamicText....</Text>.....</Table>
    </Detail>
</List>
```

In above structure My text element itself is feeled with XML structure I want to generate the report in. So I just want to append all the content of my xml and write it in outputstream. Please suggest, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In case of *Text* elements,

```
public void startText(ITextContent text)
```

or

```
public void startData(IDataContent data) throws BirtException
```

will be called but in case of **Dynamic Text** element

```
public void startForeign(IForeignContent foreign) throws BirtException
```

will be called.

You can use the below code snippet to get the dynamic text value

```
@Override
public void startForeign(IForeignContent foreign) throws BirtException {        
    Object rawValue = foreign.getRawValue();    
}
```